# Entity list not serializing as expected

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-4, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web Api controller that returns a list of Species entities:

```
public class SpeciesController : ApiController
{
    private MyEntities db = new MyEntities();

    // GET api/Default1
    public IEnumerable<Species> GetSpecies()
    {
        return db.Species.AsEnumerable();
    }
```

If I place a breakpoint in GetSpecies and fire off a quick watch on db.Species.AsEnumerable(), I see three species, each complete with ID and Name.

However, if I examine the results from my browser, I get this XML:

```
<ArrayOfSpecies>
<Species z:Id="i1">
<EntityKey z:Id="i2">
*snip*
</EntityKey>
<ConversionFactors>
*snip*
</ConversionFactors>
<Id>1</Id>
<Name>Spruce/J Pine/Fir</Name>
</Species>
<Species z:Ref="i47"/>
<Species z:Ref="i35"/>
</ArrayOfSpecies>
```

So I have three Species elements, one for each item, but why is only the first item getting its Id and Name properties populated? Why are the other elements empty?

Comment: What is an `ApiController`?

Comment: It is hard to tell without knowing what kind HTTP stack you have. What delegating handlers do, what kind filters, you have, what attributes are applied to your models, etc.

Comment: What do your actual Species objects look like? Do they have the Id field assigned to them and are not pulling through as null?